# Can't Install socket.io in Laravel Vagrant Homestead

Tags: laravel-4, socket.io, npm, vagrant

**Problem** Can't install socket.io in laravel vagrant homestead. Bellow error was thrown.

**Command** *npm install socket.io*

**Error**

```
    > ws@0.5.0 install /home/vagrant/Code/dota2/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/node_m
    odules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
    > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

    make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/Code/dota2/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io
    /node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
      COPY Release/bufferutil.node
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
      COPY Release/validation.node
    make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/Code/dota2/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/
    node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
    npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../ws/bin/wscat'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-30-generic
    npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/Code/dota2/nodejs
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path ../ws/bin/wscat
    npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
    npm ERR! errno -1
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant/Homestead virtual machine can't handle binary links.

Instead of

```
npm install socket.io
```

use

```
npm install socket.io --no-bin-links
```